# Converting Decimal to Double in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, double, decimal

I have a variable which is storing as decimal:

```
decimal firststYrComp = Int16.Parse(tb1stYr.Text.ToString());
```

Now I have this to get typecasted into Double? How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want to use Double.Parse(tb1stYr.Text.ToString()) in the first place?

Comment: Yes! I want to store integer into this format: 00.000. Decimal does that. Can double does that too? Just out of curiosity!

Comment: NET - I wouldn't normally say anything but you really should think about changing your Display Name its extremely unprofessional.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You answered your own question—Just cast it to a double:

```
decimal x  = 3.141592654M ;
double  pi = (double) x ;
```

Comment: It would be neat if you include a comment with the representation of the result of the cast.

Comment: Can casting a `decimal` to a `double` ever fail though? What happens when it's a narrowing-conversion?

Comment: try to cast 10500000000.000000000000, you'll get 10499999999.999998 with .net6! (works with .net 4.7.2)

Comment: @Thomas — Binary floating point traces precision for range. You need to read Goldberg's 1991 paper, [_What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic_](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/103162.103163). See also this website: [_What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, Or, Why Don’t My Numbers Add Up?_](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 42):

You can use decimal's built in converter.

```
decimal decimalValue = 5; 
double doubleValue = decimal.ToDouble(decimalValue);
```

Answer (score 17):

Just Try

```
Decimal yourDecimal = 3.222222m;

Convert.ToDouble(yourDecimal);
```