# Test whether a decimal value can be converted to double

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

What's a good method to test whether a `decimal` value can be converted to `double` without throwing an exception and preferrably without converting to and parsing from a string?

I can test for compatibility with the `long` or `int` types like this: (yet untested)

```
if (value == decimal.Truncate(value))
{
    if (value >= int.MinValue && value <= int.MaxValue)
        return (int)value;
    if (value >= long.MinValue && value <= long.MaxValue)
        return (long)value;
    return value.ToStringInvariant();
}
// Now try double, else revert to string again
```

This method should be used to serialise a `decimal` value to something that can be sent to JavaScript. Here, MessagePack is used but JSON should have the same constraints. `decimal` is not supported in both.

I could just always send the value as `string` but I'd like to save a bit bandwidth and use the simplest type that can represent the value (with decent precision).

PS: This doesn't compile:

```
if (value >= double.MinValue && value <= double.MaxValue)
    return (double)value;
```

I cannot compare `decimal` with `double`. What would be a good solution, if this is a good path at all?

Comment: Note, "can be converted without throwing" and "can be converted without loss of precision" are two different things

Comment: I know. Exact precision is not important here because JavaScript wouldn't be able to make use of it anyway. Throwing exceptions to find out the conversion failed is not acceptable. I'll be converting tons of values.

Comment: In that case, the range of a double is significantly greater than the range of a decimal, so you'll always be able to turn a decimal into a double. You may lose precision because a decimal has many bits more of precision than a decimal, but if that's not important...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571485/converting-decimal-to-double-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's a good method to test whether a decimal value can be converted to double without throwing an exception?

```
static bool CanBeConvertedToDouble(decimal d)
{
  return true;
}
```

:)

All decimals can be converted to double.

Note that doing so will possibly lose immense amounts of *precision*. A decimal has about 29 decimal places of precision; a double has only 15 or so. But converting a decimal to double never loses *magnitude*.